# Simple workflow with angularJs and laravel 4

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, laravel-4

I start with say that i'm really new with `angularJs` and i felt it really useful on big environment of web application.

After some research and documentations i got in some questions that in first it has confused me on how to implement it to server side languages (in my case PHP with laravel 4.1 on the base) because `angularJs` has routes and templating etc... so it's a properly framework that can work even stand alone.

Let's dig better on where i want arrive to understand the workflow with this 2 framework.

---

**1st- Questions**

How i saw on some resources with angularJs is pretty easy show up the results in json and binding with the dom. I even saw some developers print out the results with angularJs on the first load of the dom instead use a single function on the laravel controller and handle the results with laravel.

I think it's not properly useful in terms of compatibility because angular is working IE 8 and after and if i disable javascript same i dont't see the results. Instead if i use laravel 4 how first handler the first results i'll see it always! This is an example that i saw.

**Route Laravel**

```
// set 2 types of route, the first for get the json results for do handle to Angular
// the second route for display the view
Route::get('users','UserController@getUsers');
Route::get('/','UserController@getIndex);
```

**UserController Laravel**

```
public function getUsers() {

$users = User::all();
return $users; // return all users in json

}

public function getIndex() {

   return View:make('index');

}
```

**AngularJs**

```
module.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

   users: function() {
         return $http.get('/users').then(function(result){
                    return result.data;
                });
   };

});
```

**On the View**

```
<div ng-repeat="users in user">{{ user }} </div>
```

Hey! if my page have 20 queries of results i don't wanna do 20 routes and angular functions.
It's right what i said? But if they do like so should be some reason.

---

**2nd - Question**

How i said before i'm using angularjs with laravel 4.1 there is any possibility that i'll use the routes of angularJs? On my opinion is No. Because i handle my route with laravel 4.

---

**3rd - Quenstion**

Best way to show up results after a call `ajax` and bind it to my template. Maybe this question can totally go against to my first question, because if i setup my application  with that logic i have all ready for the future call `ajax`, without rewrite partial template of my results.

Let's say that i want paginate the previous results so i'll go to do a call `ajax` for show the next or previous results. If i follow the logic that i saw (first example) the only thing i have to do is push the new results on the previous object `json`.

instead if i use `laravel` how first handler of my results (normal return view and foreach), after the call `ajax` i have to create single template for show up the results with the same style and append the results. How you show up the results and which is the best method to do it?

---

Comment: You use angular for all the views, templates, etc, and laravel as a rest server that only returns json data.

Comment: Thanks, but let's say that my home page has 20 different widgets, I should do 20 calls ajax to show the results with angular. I think that's not make sense. How you do manage that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all AngularJs handle frontend routing itself. Your laravel service should be used only as RESTful api (as carlosdubusm mentioned).

If you don't want to make 20 calls you can always make angular service that will handle one call to get all the data you need, parse it and provide to controllers, directives, etc.

Angular is working asynchronously so if you wrap your code with promise it will handle data change by itself.

I hope this is what you wanted to know.

//EDIT:

**promise example**

```
$scope.user = {
        name    : '',
        email   : ''
    };

$scope.updateUserInfo = function (response) {
        $scope.user = response;
    };

// users model have rest calls to api using restangular
usersModel.getMyInfo()
.then($scope.updateUserInfo);
```

**service sample**

```
'use strict';
app.factory('alertService', function ($timeout){
    return new AlertService($timeout);
});

var AlertService = function($timeout) {
    this.queue = [];
    this.alerts = [];

    var AlertService = this;

    this.TYPE_INFO = 0;
    this.TYPE_SUCCESS = 1;
    this.TYPE_ALERT = 2;
    this.TYPE_ERROR = 3;

    this.add = function (msg, type) {
        var alert = new AlertItem(msg, type);
        AlertService.queue.push(alert);
        AlertService.alerts.push(alert);

        $timeout(function (){
            AlertService.closeAlert(alert);
        }, 10000);
    };

    this.closeAlert = function (alert) {
        return AlertService.queue.splice(AlertService.queue.indexOf(alert),1);
    };

    this.getAlerts = function (){
        return AlertService.queue;
    };

    this.getAll = function () {
        return this.alerts;
    };

};

var AlertItem = function(msg, type) {

    var TYPE_CLASS = {
        0: "alert-info",
        1: "alert-success",
        2: "",
        3: "alert-error"
    };

    var type = type;
    var msg = msg;

    this.getType = function() {
        return type;
    };

    this.getClass = function () {
        return TYPE_CLASS[type];
    };

    this.getMsg = function () {
        return msg;
    };

};
```

Comment: Thank you, now is a little bit more clear thanks. Can you link me somewhere to get start with this kind of approach? :)

Comment: For services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services, for routing: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07. In answer edit I've added example service for displaying alerts from any place you want.